# How to run sudo command with no password?

Tags: sudo, aws

**How does the `ubuntu` user on the AWS images for Ubuntu Server 12.04 have passwordless `sudo` for all commands when there is no configuration for it in `/etc/sudoers`?**

I'm using Ubuntu server 12.04 on Amazon. I want to add a new user that has the same behavior as the default Ubuntu user. Specifically I want passwordless `sudo` for this new user.

So I've added a new user and went to edit `/etc/sudoers` (using visudo of course). From reading that file it seemed like the default `ubuntu` user was getting it's passwordless `sudo` from being a member of the `admin` group. So I added my new user to that. Which didn't work. Then I tried adding the `NOPASSWD` directive to `sudoers`. Which also didn't work.

Anyway, now I'm just curious. How does the `ubuntu` user get passwordless privileges if they aren't defined in `/etc/sudoers`. What is the mechanism that allows this?

Comment: Related: [Execute sudo without Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password)

Answer (score 393, accepted):

Okay, I have discovered the answer so may as well put it here for completeness. At the end of `/etc/sudoers` there is what I thought was just a comment:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

However this actually includes the contents of that directory. Inside of which is the file 
`/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu`. Which has the expected contents

```
# ubuntu user is default user in cloud-images.
# It needs passwordless sudo functionality.
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

So that is where the sudo configuration for the default ubuntu user lives.

You should edit this file using visudo. The following command will let you edit the correct file with visudo.

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu
```

And add a line like:

```
aychedee ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

At the end.

Comment: I am currently struggling with `/etc/sudoers` on ubuntu-12.04 (desk x86_64). After altering `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d/*`, do I need to reboot, logout or `sudo restart` any daemon?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had to do a full reboot.

Comment: new sudo rules will be used for every new logged user - so you need re login at least

Comment: 'sudo service sudo restart'
works :)

Comment: In later versions (14.04 for example) the included file is `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` (so to edit.. `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`). Although it'd be cleaner to create additional files than editing the generated one. Note that files containing a `.` or ending in `~` will *not* be included.

Comment: IMHO that should be changed. #include is something that could really throw someone off. This case is a perfect example.  How about @Include instead?

Comment: This is a great spot. I always wondered how the ubuntu user could `sudo -i` without a password and without the NOPASSWD part in `/etc/sudoers` I thought I was going crazy or something. # at the start of a line in a config file which isn't a comment is flagrant abuse of common standards.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Most likely, it was added as a comment to allow compatibility with other (standard?) versions of sudo, which don't allow includes, but wouldn't be tripped up by a weird comment. (Standards are hard! ;-)

Comment: because who has a time to `man sudoers 5` to check `#includedir` directive 

Comment: Nothing works for me. ec2 instance. I added file in sudoers.d, I added my user in visudo with ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL, I added my user to wheel group and I commented out the wheel so all members have passwordless sudo. Nothing at all worked. And I don't even have sudo service. It's not in systemctl either.

Comment: Might be worth noting that `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` is not commented out. In other words, do not remove the `#`, the `#` must be there for the `/etc/sudoers` file to be valid.

Comment: Just to clarify, do not add `aychedee` on that line, add YOUR username.

Comment: If you are in server environment like me & cannot restart, wait for 15 minutes to get effect. Apparently there is a timeout.

Answer (score 113):

I found that the most straight forward thing to do, in order to easily replicate this behavior across multiple servers, was the following:

```
sudo visudo
```

Change this line:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to this line:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

And move it **under** this line:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

you should now have this:

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

then for every user that needs sudo access **WITH a password**:

```
sudo adduser <user> sudo
```

and for every user that needs sudo access **WITH NO password**:

```
sudo adduser <user> admin
```

(on older versions of ubuntu, you may need to):

```
sudo service sudo restart
```

And that's it!

**Edit:** You may have to add the admin group as I don't think it exists by default.

```
sudo groupadd admin
```

You can also add the default AWS `ubuntu` user to the `admin` group via this command:

```
sudo usermod ubuntu -g admin
```

Note: As [@hata](https://askubuntu.com/users/456960/hata) mentioned, you may need to use `adm` as your admin group name, depending on which version of Ubuntu is being used.

Comment: Note to self: It's a convention to move less restrictive permissions lower in the stack. But not doing it won't affect functionality.

Comment: As jiminikiz explained, I had to place the *%admin* after the *%sudo* on my Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS. Plus, the administrators group id is exactly not *admin* but *adm* on my Ubuntu. No reboot was required.

Comment: by the way use `sudo apt purge nano` if you want to default to vi on your system.

Answer (score 9):

I would create my own file under /etc/sudoers.d/ directory - the file created by Amazon Cloud might be overwritten in case of any update. After creating your file in /etc/sudoers.d, add this entry,

```
<your user name> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Reboot the system and this will work.

Answer (score 7):

*Short answer without using any editor (tested on bash, very risky to execute on remote hosts).*

Configure sudo to work without a password for the current user:

```bash
echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers
```

Check the edit with:

```bash
sudo visudo -c
```

Verify if you can use sudo without a password:

```bash
sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep "$USER"
```

...or simply try it with:

```bash
sudo <anything>
```

Comment: This is pretty dangerous advice... copy and paste this wrong and you'll lock yourself out of your own server. Hence the advice to use visudo. It checks that the syntax is correct before saving to disk. So, for anyone that wants to use this. Don't do it on a remote server that you care about. You might want to include a warning about that in your answer.

Comment: Not using visudo is a *horrible* idea.  Trust me, I know.

Comment: IMHO, a copy-paste is safer than a manual edit. A minor simplification: `echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers`

Comment: @theartofrain - Normally, I'd agree, but `visudo` is particularly nice about not allowing you to break the sudoers file, thus not locking you out of your machine (or at least sudo).

Comment: @JonV You can lose admin rights via `visudo` too, but usually not by accident, because `visudo` only saves changes that are well-formed according to [the grammar for sudoers files](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/sudoers.5.html). *Most* mistakes are syntactically wrong, so they cause no harm with `visudo`. If `/etc/sudoers` or a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` *is* ill-formed, `sudo` refuses to elevate privileges for anyone as a security measure, which is why not using `visudo` is dangerous. (Though [sometimes `pkexec` can fix it](https://askubuntu.com/a/73872) without a reboot.)

Answer (score 2):

As I was researching this, I realized that there's a line in the `/etc/sudoers` file that is not a comment, but a **directive** that makes any file or folder under the directory `/etc/sudoers/*` override the contents of `/etc/sudoers`.

This is a sneaky little directive, as it appears to be a commented line upon first glance. It looks like this:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

This is how I've implemented the non-root, passwordless user in an ephemeral Docker Image for use in a CICD pipeline with the base image of `ubuntu:18.04`:

```
RUN \
  useradd -U foo -m -s /bin/bash -p foo -G sudo && passwd -d foo && passwd -d root && \
  sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
  sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
  sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## Removed the #include directive! ##"/g' && \
  echo "Customized the sudoers file for passwordless access!" && \
  echo "foo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
  echo "root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
  echo "foo user:";  su foo -c 'whoami && id' && \
  echo "root user:"; su root -c 'whoami && id'
```

What happens with the above code:

- The user and group `foo` is created.
- The user `foo` is added to the both the `foo` and `sudo` group.
- The home directory is set to `/home/foo`.
- The shell is set to `/bin/bash`.
- The passwords for both `foo` and `root` are deleted.
- The `sed` command does inline updates to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow `foo` and `root` users passwordless access to the `sudo` command.
- The `sed` command disables the **`#includedir`** directive that would allow any files in subdirectories to override these inline updates.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to remove password

`sudo passwd -d user`

check more info about passwd command with `passwd -h` on ubuntu

edit:
passwd command varies from system to system. for eg the -d flag is on ubuntu systems but not on macbooks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason every answer here seems way longer than it should be or is unnecessarily complex.

Here's the fool-proof way to do it:

Run:

```bash
$ echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
```

Copy the output of that.

Then run:

```bash
$ sudo visudo
```

Paste the line you copied in the previous step, at the bottom of this file.