# Is there a program to mount all of my drives automatically?

Tags: mount

Sometimes when I restart my computer, my drives will mount but sometimes they won't (like right now when I'm typing this question out).

Is there an easy way, like a program that can mount them for me? Going in the console, making folders, etc, is NOT what I want. I like how Windows does it where they always mount the drives no matter what.

If there isn't a program how else can I easily mount all drives?

Comment: Operating system? File manager?

Comment: @vasa1 I'm using an unmodified/vanilla version of Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Okay, so the file manager will be Nautilus.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**This works in 12.10 - 16.10**

Type Disks in Dash, and you will get:

[image]

Click on the little gears icon, to get the sub menu, and choose Edit Mount Options.  After that you will see:

[image]

Change the Automatic Mount Options to ON.  do that to all the drives that you need mounted on start-up.

**Note: Be careful with what you modify, it may cause the system not to work properly.**

Comment: This is excellent advice. Many people are used to *having* to edit `/etc/fstab` manually. While that's appropriate and useful in many situations, it's good to know that a volume's mount options can be customized with the reasonably user-friendly GUI in *Disks*.

Comment: Will this also work with encrypted drives?

Comment: @TomBrossman I just created an encrypted disk, and unfortunately it will not work with it.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility` if it isn't installed by default in your Ubuntu-based distro. This solution worked in Ubuntu Mate 15.04

Comment: Also it is good to backup `/etc/fstab` like `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab_backup` before using the disk utility, since it would modify `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Also tick "show in user interface" if you want to display it in devices list.

Comment: Method is still on in 17.04

Answer (score 15):

### How to auto mount NTFS part/disks in Ubuntu

Press the Ubuntu button, start your `disks` application.

[image: disks]

select your NTFS Partition/Disk? Press the configuration button select `Edit Mount Options...`

[image: Edit Mount Options]

Turn `off` the `Automatic Mount Options`, `select Mount at startup`. choose your `Display Name` Like `Data` or `partition-Data` or `seriously-not-porn`, whichever best describes your personality?!

[image: Mount Options window]

`Mount Point` means where do you want it to be mounted! this could be `/mnt/DATA//home/username/part-data` or `/home/username/Videos/no-porno` again, what best describes your personality! After that Press OK, type in your password, again OK. and restart your system, and see your mounted HardDiskdrive.

**source**

- [How To: auto mount NTFS part/disks in Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-mount-ntfs-part-disk-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this by your own script (without using any program), then the following may help you:

Create file named `automount` in [`/usr/local/bin`](https://askubuntu.com/q/465109/256099) and give it execution permission (`sudo chmod +x`).

- ###case-1 : [sudo without password](https://askubuntu.com/q/192050/256099) (If you have set `NOPASSWD` in `/etc/sudoers`:-)

  Contents for `/usr/local/bin/automount`:

  ```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd /dev/disk/by-label
    for label in *
    do
        partition=$(basename $(readlink $label))
        sudo mkdir /media/$USER/$label
        sudo mount /dev/$partition /media/$USER/$label
    done
    exit
  ```

  Then create [Startup Application](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/256099) (**`gnome-session-properties`**) and add the following:

[image: screenshot]

- ###case-2 : sudo needs password (If you have not set `NOPASSWD` in `/etc/sudoers`):-

  Contents for `/usr/local/bin/automount`:

  ```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd /dev/disk/by-label
    user=$(zenity --entry --text="Enter Username")
    for label in *
    do
        partition=$(basename $(readlink $label))
        sudo mkdir /media/$user/$label
        sudo mount /dev/$partition /media/$user/$label
    done
    exit
  ```

Alternatively you can set `<username>` permanently instead of `$user`.

Then create [Startup Application](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/256099) (**`gnome-session-properties`**) and add following:

[image: screenshot2]

Note: For running `gksudo`, the package [`gksu`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gksu&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) must be installed. If not, first do: `sudo apt-get install gksu`

---

Additional Notes:

- This script mounts partitions on `/media/$USER/<Disk-Label>`.
- To check/change labels of your partition, you can use `gnome-disk-utility`:

[image: gnome-disk-utility]

[image: screenshotforlabel]

Answer (score 1):

In the "Mount Options" window, be sure to UNCHECK the "Show In User Interface" option if you make changes using this utility.  There is a [KNOWN BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1012081) that can cause the mounting to fail and even make your system unbootable if you use the DISKS utility to change these options and leave "Show in User Interface" checked.

That bug will show up as stating that the commend "x-gvfs-show" is not recognized or that there is a parameter missing when trying to mount that partition.

Comment: Thanks, helped me heaps, kept having to log into the terminal when 'startx' failed and type "sudo mount -no remount,rw /" to get ubuntu to boot each time...

Comment: This bug was fixed in utopic (Ubuntu 14.10), afaict.

Answer (score 0):

For people used to MS windows behavior there is the Gigolo app which is available on Ubuntu or Linux Mint through the software manager.

https://www.maketecheasier.com/manage-remote-filesystems-with-gigolo/

https://codepre.com/how-to-install-gigolo-in-ubuntu-a-best-application-for-linux-to-manage-remote-file-system.html

Once you configure it and set the automount options there, you can set it to your "startup" programs and if all your mounts are available it will connect them. (Note: it will keep reconnecting very few minutes if not available, similar to MS windows so if you want to disconnect a mount longer term/permanent it's best to turn the automount on the drive off)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the drives you want to mount you can write a shell script like the following to mount the drives. In my case I need to mount Windows drives within my Ubuntu subsystem for Linux, so my script looks like:

```
for i in 1
do
    sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c
    sudo mount -t drvfs F: /mnt/f
    sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g
done
```