# Is there a user friendly way of mounting an external drive that was ejected?

Tags: mount, gui

I have a very noisy external 500 GB drive which I use mostly for synchronizing local files.

In OS X I used to eject the drive, and mount it later when I need it with the [Disk Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Utility).

Is there a GUI for doing so in Ubuntu?

Comment: See if [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-my-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527) can help.

Comment: Thanks. These options do help in that I can set the drive to sleep after a short interval (this drive didn't sleep in Windows 7). It still woke up randomly when I was not accessing it though. EDIT: Oh wait.. this could help, but if it does not auto mount, how do you mount it?

Comment: Click on the little square on the far left. (First image left of the first red arrow)in [The same](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-my-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527) question.

Comment: Dohhh! The "stop" button becomes "play" button for an unmounted drive. I didn't notice it, such a small icon. Well that answers my question: I am able to mount the drive with the click of a button in Ubuntu. If you add an answer here I can accept the answer, thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu also has a `Disk Utility` application which serves this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try **gparted**:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: Gparted certainly seems to be an overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: :) i agree..certainly...

Answer (score 0):

The other question is about "auto mount" features. My question was specifically about the ability to mount a drive *that I ejected myself in the same session*, via GUI.

This can be done in the **Disks** program, as Mitch pointed out in the comments:

- Click on the drive, and look for the little square icon below the graph with the partitions.
- When the device is mounted, clicking this icon will unmount the drive ("stop").
- When the device is not mounted, the icon will show a "play" arrow instead (similar to a music player). Clicking the "play" button will mount the drive.

I feel this question is relevant, because in Windows 7 I never found a way to do this. If I ejected my (very noisy) Seagate USB hardrive, I would be unable to mount it again short of restarting Windows or pulling and plugging the cable again.