# Detect and mount devices

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, usb-drive, partitioning

I upgraded Ubuntu today and everything works smooth except that Ubuntu doesn't detect any other storage devices. My `/` and `/home` partitions work fine, but my other partitions are just not detected. I wouldn't mind, except the same problem goes with USB sticks.

When I plug in a USB stick, the light goes on, but the computer detects nothing. Just to be clear, my mouse and keyboard are connected via USB and work fine.

Any idea how to solve this issue? None of the suggestions I found on the internet have any effect.

Comment: What's the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: Just to make sure I got this, this is stand-alone Ubuntu not in virtual machine, right?
Run `sudo fdisk -l` in terminal and post the output.

Comment: Have you tried my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-my-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527)

Comment: What is the output of df -h ? Is the USB device listed there?

Comment: In case of latest portable HDDs they could be mounted again once they left not connected for few hours(>6h). Observed this in Transcend and Seagate 2TB Expansion

Answer (score 266):

**Solution 1**: Try the Disks program (if you run Ubuntu **with a GUI**).

(check that the gnome-disk-utility package is installed)
(make sure that udisks2 package is installed)

Hit <kbd>SUPER</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to open the Application Lens and type `Disks` in the Search Applications field.

(<kbd>SUPER</kbd> is probably the key with the Windows icon.)

In Disks you can play with the automount options.     ......

For example:

[image: Disks Program]

You have to click on the little icon with the two gears and choose 'Edit Mount Options'.

[image: Mount Options]

**Solution 2**: Using the **CLI** (for a headless installation)

Step 1. Check the blockdevices and the file systems that are assigned to those block devices.

```
lsblk
```

[image: lsblk]

Here you see the blokdevice sdb with partition /sdb1. But it's not mounted. There's no file assigned to it.

Step 2. What kind of device is sdb?

```
sudo lshw
```

or

```
sudo lshw | less
```

[image: lshw]

So the USB stick - the block device /sdb - has the logical name /dev/sdb. And the FAT32 filesystem on that stick has the logical name /dev/sdb1.

Step 3. Mounting the USB-stick

We will mount /dev/sdb1 to /media/usbstick

```
sudo mkdir /media/usbstick

sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usbstick
```

Read the manpage of mount for other options.

Step 4. Did it work?

```
lsblk
```

[image: lsblk 2]

Yes, we can see that the filesystem on the USB stick is mounted to /media/usbstick

**Addendum** : if there are no logical names like /dev/sdb, you should first create them.  See this [information about setting up and controling loop devices with the losetup command](http://samindaw.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/mounting-a-file-as-a-file-system-in-linux/)

Comment: I like this post a whole lot actually, lsblk looks like a great program. Too bad it doesnt come with ubuntu

Comment: lsblk is in the util-linux package (at least in 12.04.2 LTS)

Comment: Looks like the link at the end mis-directs to an image.

Comment: I can only access the drive with root, how can I add users?

Comment: Found the answer: "chown -R yourUsernameHere:yourUsernameHere /media/usbstick/"

Answer (score 81):

`sudo lsusb` will tell you what USB devices Linux detects. Whether a USB storage device mounts, or is detected, are separate issues. `sudo lsusb -v` will give verbose output, possibly more information than you want if the OS truly doesn't recognize the device.

Alternatively, you could compare the lists of devices in `/dev` before and after plugging in the USB device. There are many ways to do it; I would probably just use:

```
ls -l /dev/* | wc -l
```

This will give you a number of recognized devices. Doing it before and after plugging in a device will tell you if the OS assigned the device in `/dev/`.

Another option would be to look at what is happening in `dmesg` when you plug in the USB device. `dmesg` may tell you things like how a device failed.

If the USB device you are having trouble mounting, is on the lsusb list, then you can try mounting the device. At this point it would be good to know the filesystem type. `sudo fdisk -l` will tell you the filesystem type, in the form of an ID. You may have to look up the ID number. There are lots of references online for that. Once you know the device listing, that is, `/dev/hda1` and the filesystem type you can try to mount the device manualy with the `mount` command.

```
sudo mount /dev/hda1 /home/user/Desktop/whereEver
```

You may have to make sure the location you want to mount the device on exists. If the OS recognizes the file system, then `mount` might just work if the file system is not a native file system type; you may have to specify flags for mounting.

Post back your output from `dmesg` (not all of it, only from around when the USB device is plugged in), and `sudo lsusb`.

You may find *[Linux / UNIX: Device files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-unix-linux-bsd-device-files/)* helpful if trying to determine device type.

I am writing this assuming all your unrecognized devices are block type devices.
There are many ways to approach this type of problem and many possible solutions. More specific information is needed to provide a solution.

There are also many GUI applications that can do the same thing. You might try looking for the plugged-in hardware in the "Disk Utility".

Comment: why use dmesg instead of fdisk? because using fdisk assumes your hardware is working. If your hardware fails, fdisk wont tell you. but dmesg will.

Answer (score 21):

### Manually Mount a USB Drive

A USB storage device plugged into the system usually mounts automatically, but if for some reasons it doesn't automount, it's possible to manually mount it with these steps.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to run Terminal.
2. Enter `sudo mkdir /media/usb` to create a mount point called ***usb***.
3. Enter `sudo fdisk -l` to look for the USB drive already plugged in, let's say the drive you want to mount is `/dev/sdb1`.
4. To mount a USB drive formatted with **FAT16** or **FAT32** system, enter:

   ```
   sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usb -o uid=1000,gid=100,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
   ```

   OR, To mount a USB drive formatted with **NTFS** system, enter:

   ```
   sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
   ```

To unmount it, just enter `sudo umount /media/usb` in the Terminal.

[source](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-ubuntu-after-installation-ubuntu-1404.htm#Manually-Mount-USB-Drive)

Answer (score 11):

You can use one of the following commands to get information details about mounted devices:
all different commands are used to getting different information in different  manners, results ...

- dmesg
- sudo fdisk   OR sudo fdisk -l
- sudo blkid
- lsblk
- mount
- lsusb
- usb-devices
- df -h

Answer (score 4):

You only mention one storage device type - usb stick. Whenever usb devices don't mount correctly check that you **don't have** package called **usbmount installed**. If it is, remove it and life should be back to normal after that (you might need to restart).

Comment: Nice program. When I run it together with udisks2 and plug-in my USB stick it complains that it's already mounted :-)

Comment: I once had it in my system and usb sticks were (if at all) mounted as root and so I could not write to them. Took quite a while to figure this one out.

Comment: Is ```x2gothinclient-usbmount``` the same as ```usbmount```, my system is 22.04 LTS?

Answer (score 3):

I too had similar situation where my pen drive became invisible.

I solved it by  using the Ubuntu utility program named **Disks**. Inside the disk tool, the pen drive was visible. I clicked on the gear icon inside disk(make sure that you have selected the correct device) and the used the format partition option with **FAT** (compatible with all systems and devices)