# alternative ways of mounting USB NTFS external-hdd

Tags: mount, hard-drive, usb-drive, ntfs, external-hdd

I mount my Samsung hard disk through this command `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/Samsung`

**BUT** it doesn't work *except after* running the command `sudo f-disk -l` and waiting for it about 5 minutes to finish! Every time I need mount the hard disk I have to wait 5 minutes!! This is really really bugging me.

Are there any other ways to try to mount this hard disk? Maybe through some program? Or maybe by granting the hard disk extra permissions or whatever? ?? ???

*ask me for any extra information you need to know.* It's a 500GB hard disk.

*you can look at the question I asked when I didn't know how to mount the hard disk at first*: [Ubuntu doesn't "see" external USB Hard Disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318987/ubuntu-doesnt-see-external-usb-hard-disk)

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

You could add it to your `/etc/fstab` file using the UUID.

To get the UUID you need to do a `sudo blkid` and find your device there.

Example:

`/dev/sdc1: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ntfs"`

Then you take the UUID and add an entry to the `fstab`. It looks something like this:

`UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  /media/yourdevice   ntfs    defaults 0 0`

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't solve it. ...I knew from my general knowledge that fstab is used for automatic mounting or mounting at startup; I didn't think it would work. thanks for the effort anyways. :) (sorry for the -1)