# Ubuntu not mounting brand-new external drive

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I bought a brand new 3TB external drive for my birthday coming up, It's a WD My Book, it came as NTFS, and I'm trying to make it mount using a simple script on boot. (Not `/etc/fstab`, I ruined my comp. using that by accident and had to re-install).

I'm instead having a script run in `/etc/init.d`. The thing is, it's under `/dev/sdf` and I want it to mount in `/exhd`, the script seems to run, but it doesn't mount it.

Any help here, please?

Comment: Could you post the contents of the script?  Just to make sure you're aware, /dev/sdf refers to the device - partitions on the device will have numbers after them (e.g. /dev/sdf1, /dev/sdf2).  It's those numbered devices you need to mount.

Comment: Can you see the disk in the program 'disks'?

Comment: try following [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318987/ubuntu-doesnt-see-external-usb-hard-disk/380580#380580)

Comment: I suspect a permissions error somewhere (mount point or script), does it mount through the commandline? You should really just try using fstab properly  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

Comment: @crasic It appears I was looking in the wrong place, the disk did appear in disks, but I was looking at /dev/sdf, not /dev/sdf1, so the system was trying to mount whatever /dev/sdf is instead of my drive.

Comment: @user245115 `/dev/sdf` refers to the **entire** disk as a single file. It will fail to mount because it does not point to the beginning of a partition with FS information. The OS automatically reads the partition table of `/dev/sdf` to determine the number/location of partitions and populates them as `/dev/sdfX`. [More Info](http://serverfault.com/questions/338937/differences-between-dev-sda-and-dev-sda1)

Comment: Happy Birthday, Wish you the Best, You Should be Happy!

Comment: @Yousef's Thanks, even though it's in 2 days, I bought it for my early birthday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I made a mistake, when I went to the disks partition, I was looking at /dev/sdf, not /dev/sdf1, and since that happened it was trying to mount /dev/sdf instead of my external drive at /dev/sdf1, in other words, I was looking in the wrong place. It works now. My research was found here: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/mounting-a-windows-xp-ntfs-partition-in-linux/