# external HDD mount issue

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I am trying to mount my external hdd.

auto detection is not working, so I took the help of [Ubuntu doesn't "see" external USB Hard Disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318987/ubuntu-doesnt-see-external-usb-hard-disk)

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

giving this result:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000170586112 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121597 cylinders, total 1953458176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00023f15

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   976893951   488445952    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       976893952  1953454079   488280064    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

```
    dmesg | tail -n 20
```

giving below result:

```
[ 1005.269557] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1005.269560] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1005.269562] Read(10): 28 00 3a 37 b7 f8 00 00 08 00
[ 1005.269571] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 976730104
[ 1005.269576] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 122091007
[ 1023.014446] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 1023.014454] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1023.014458] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 1023.014460] Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[ 1023.014465] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 1023.014467] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1023.014470] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1023.014472] Read(10): 28 00 3a 37 b7 f8 00 00 08 00
[ 1023.014483] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 976730104
[ 1023.014489] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 122091007
[ 1028.584023] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1028.584866] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1028.585716] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1032.915263] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 1032.915272] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

I tried to use below command also:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

and this also:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ -t auto
```

but I got same error:

> mount: you must specify the filesystem type

I have just started using ubuntu.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the following:

```
exfat-fuse - read and write exFAT driver for FUSE
exfat-utils - utilities to create, check, label and dump exFAT filesystem
```

So your computer can finally see the `exFAT` formatted stick of yours. to install use the following line in terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install exfat*
```

Comment: Thanks @Videonauth, I install exfat, as suggested by you. But still i am not able to mount. I tried command 'sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hdp1 -t exFAT' but i got this error 'mount: unknown filesystem type ''exFAT' '

Comment: Did you try to simly reboot and use `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hdp1`? This normaly should suffice after the drivers for the filesystem are there.

Comment: yes,  getting error 'mount: you must specify the filesystem type'

Comment: Do you have important data on that stick? Means would it hurt to reformat it, as far i can read from your OP that there are I/O errors as well. Or the Chance to test the stick on an other machine?

Comment: yes, its eems some bad sector or someting, getting this error msg  when tried command 'sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hdp1 -t ntfs'    ...... 'Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice.'

Comment: I can only think of two option right now as i read this, either try to check the stick with windows or reformat it.