# My external hard drives (1 TB ADATA Classic CH11 and 1 TB Western Digital My passport Ultra) are not being recognized

Tags: hard-drive

Good morning everybody, I am very new to Ubuntu and this website so excuse me if I make a mistake putting this question in here if it is already answer (I looked for similar questions already solved but I can't find my specific case). I have two external hard drives, a 1 TB ADATA and a 1 TB WD; neither of them are appearing in files, but they appear in certain commands in the terminal (such as lsusb or dmesg), I tried doing the mounting problem solution with the following commands:

```
ls /dev/ | grep sd 
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sdxn /mnt
```

(Replacing sdxn by the extra line you found when we did the first step)

According to this solution in askubuntu ([Ubuntu doesn't "see" external USB Hard Disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318987/ubuntu-doesnt-see-external-usb-hard-disk))

but neither of the hard drives are appearing in the ls /dev/ | grep sd command.

Normally I am a user of windows 10 and there I tried several solutions as well (such as seeing if it was recognized in disk management but was missing an assignment letter, it wasn't recognized there, seeing if it was a driver problem uninstalling all the drivers device manager that were greyed out and hidden, and that didn't work either). That was the reason I went to Ubuntu, to see if the devices were recognized there. I don't know if it is relevant information or not but I am using the Ubuntu test (as a live cd) I didn't installed it, and I am using I am using Ubuntu 16.04, I think is the last version. Please pardon my possible grammar mistakes.

These are the outputs for lsusb and dmesg (ls /dev/ | grep sd  does not change after connecting the drive) for the ADATA drive:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0248 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a05:7220 Unknown Manufacturer 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 125f:a11a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg
...
[  535.924530] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  536.130822] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=a11a
[  536.130839] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  536.130843] usb 1-1.1: Product: CH11
[  536.130846] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: ADATA
[  536.130849] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: C11A0102012101500293
[  536.357569] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  536.357691] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0
[  536.357840] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  536.511472] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

These are the outputs for lsusb and dmesg (ls /dev/ | grep sd  does not change after connecting the drive) for the WD drive together with the ADATA drive:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0248 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a05:7220 Unknown Manufacturer 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 125f:a11a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1058:0830 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport Ultra (WDBZFP)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg
...
[  611.501229] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  611.518222] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0830
[  611.518230] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  611.518233] usb 4-2: Product: My Passport 0830
[  611.518236] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[  611.518239] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 57583631413734414B433346
[  611.519199] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  611.520793] scsi host7: usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[  612.518445] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0830 1065 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  612.519074] scsi 7:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1065 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  612.520674] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  612.521405] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  612.524634] scsi 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[  612.845794] scsi 7:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 0
[  612.845801] scsi 7:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0xffffffea
[  612.845855] scsi 7:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[  612.845896] ses 7:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
```

In both cases (before and after connecting the drives) ls /dev/ | grep sd was the same:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /dev / |grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda4
sda5
sda6
```

They are not being recognized by gparted either, in windows they both appear in device and printers (the ADATA as unknown and the WD as a normal device) and are given the option to eject safely, but they do not appear in my pc, or disk management. In windows I already tried reinstalling the drivers but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop or desktop computer? How old?

Drives don't mount in BOTH Windows and Ubuntu Live CD, yes? Do these drive work on another computer?

Your USB ports may not be supplying enough power to run the external hard disks, especially if they're 7200 RPM drives (which use more current). You might try using a POWERED USB hub. Plug the hub into the computer USB port, and to the power adapter, and the external drive(s) into the hub.

Let us know.

Cheers, Al

Comment: I have a laptop, 2014, intel i3 4gb ram 750 gb hard drive intel integrated graphics card. But I have tried the drives in several computers, another laptop and desktop computers, with a diverse array of specifications. The drives don't work in all of these computers (so I tried with the Ubuntu live cd, and it didn't work). They were working in my computer and other computers before. Also I did a quick search for the rpm of each drive and both seem to run at a maximum of 5400 RPM. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Are these NTFS partitioned drives? Were they unplugged without having properly dismounting them first? If they are NTFS, you'll have to try and do a chkdsk from Windows. Cheers, Al

Comment: I'm not sure what file type they are because they are not being recognized, and I don't know how to apply chkdsk if I don't know the drive assigned letter (if there is a way I can't find it, I have never applied that command, pardon my ignorance), my best guess is they have a FAT32 file type. When I execute chkdsk on command prompt all I get is a short description of the file type and size of my internal hard drive, but the externals are no where to be found. I recently discover something that might be useful, they both appear in devices and printers, one as unknown and the other as device

Comment: In Ubuntu you can start gparted and see if you can determine what, if anything, is on these drives. Cheers, Al

Comment: I added more information about the drives in my question, maybe it will be useful info.

Comment: Wow. I'd suggest removing the hard disks from the enclosures, and attaching them directly to a sata port on a desktop computer, or getting yourself a usb->sata cable, or a usb->sata docking station.  If that works, your usb bridges in the enclosures are bad. Did these drives EVER work for you, or are they new to you? Cheers, Al

Comment: I don't have that kind of tools but that is a good advice, if I send them to a technician I will tell them that. These drives are at least two years old, they worked through both years, but they presented these failures about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your concerns, not yet no, I will send the devices with an expert in the area and see if he can do something, some partners are telling there might be a problem in the communication system between the hard drive itself and the usb component, or something like that. Thank you again, I will post the solution once I get it, if there is one that is.