# Ubuntu 16.04 - External hard disk not detected unless reboot while plugged in

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I am facing a strange issue with my `Transcend StoreJet 25H3 USB 3.0 2TB` external hard disk. Whenever I plugin my drive when the ubuntu is running and the device is not detected. Nothing show up in `fdisk`, `lsusb` or `demsg`. But if I let it plugged and restart the system then after the reboot it just works normally.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you try this: [Check if Ubuntu detects a device & How to mount a U](http://askubuntu.com/a/380580/432413)

Comment: Tried that, doesn't help, it doesn't show up in anything. and I restart I just works.

Comment: I have the same problem with different external HDDs (Samsung M3, WD Elements) and I'm pretty sure it still worked Oct. 1st. That suggests that there was a regression in some update. (I see in apt history that udev was upgraded later that day and that is the kind of packet that could cause something like that. I'll try to figure out how to rollback to check.)

Comment: I downgraded the systemd-related packages (which includes udev) to 229-4ubuntu4 and also tried booting an older kernel: No success. Looking at the history of upgraded packages since Oct. 1st, I have no idea what else could have triggered it.

Comment: Surprisingly my hard disk worked automatically later, i didn't do anything but since then, i having issues with some flash drives, some just mounts nicely and some doesn't. same with the memory cards, some gets detected, some doesn't. Its very weird.