# difficulty transferring file to android phone

Tags: 12.10, usb, mount, android

When I first connect my android phone, it gives me the open to open a folder, but I closed it and how I can't find it.

Disconnecting and reconnecting my phone doesn't give me the a chance to open the folder.

Elsewhere on askUbuntu I learned about [`lsusb`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285539/detect-and-mount-devices)

```
$ sudo lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0292 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 034: ID 1004:631e LG Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
```

[`dmesg | tail`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464106/determine-if-a-usb-is-mounted-using-lsusb-data) gives stuff like this:

```
[87199.613713] usb 2-1.2: Product: LGE Android Phone
[87199.613718] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: LG Electronics Inc.
[87199.613722] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: LG-LG870-47ff109
[87338.250539] ieee80211 phy0: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[87473.650192] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_c_ampdu_dotxstatus_complete: Pkt tx suppressed, illegal channel possibly 5
```

Could this be the reason I can no longer transfer files to my phone?

Comment: The ieee80211 messages in dmesg are about your wifi, not the phone, so likely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

While not a *direct* answer to your question, I would recommend using [Airdroid](http://airdroid.com/).  It's an app that runs a server on your phone; you can then access its contents from http://web.airdroid.com/.  It lets you transfer files to and from the phone as well as manage files, photos, SMS, etc.