# cannot mount any type of external drive

Tags: mount

i run Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit on a Lenovo y50 and i'm trying to figure out how come my laptop doesn't mount drives whenever i try to connect one. no error messages appear, just nothing happens. i've tried an sd reader connected to a 256 gb micro sd card, a lexar 64 gb usb drive, and wd 2 tb external hard drive and nothing seems to be recognized by ubuntu please help

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to check if the storage device is recognized by your system.

Disconnect your device then open a terminal and input 
`ls /dev/ | grep sd` and Enter. Now connect the device and input `ls /dev/ | grep sd` again and Enter. Now you should have two outputs. Compare them to each other.

You should find an extra line (or two) in the second output.
 You can check more about detecting drives [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285539/detect-and-mount-devices/289137#289137)

Now if it is detecting then mount the disk by using the command

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

where sda1 is the name of the extra drive that appeared.
You can find more about mount command [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount).

P.S:- You can run the command and post it's output here.

`lsusb`

`sudo fdisk -l`

`dmesg | tail`

Comment: unfortunately when i enter the command again after connecting the drive, both results are the same and no extra lines are present

Comment: Try to use the drive with a windows pc. If it works with Windows, unmount the drive safely from windows and then try to connect to Ubuntu and check if it works for you.

Comment: i factually did try that but nothing changed. ubuntu was still unable to recognize the drive

Comment: now for some reason whenever i connect the sd reader to my laptop it gives me an error message "Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /media/bluntk0nkussi0n/AE9E-B3F4: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/mmcblk0p1" "/media/bluntk0nkussi0n/AE9E-B3F4"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'"

also i ran the code you mentioned in the ps and will post it in the next comment

Comment: Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 174f:14b8 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: idk what to do about the second line of code bc the output is too long to post in this comment...

Comment: [41804.542766] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link up
[41809.852788] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link down
[41813.025944] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link up
[41814.684453] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link down
[41817.866405] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link up
[41857.894344] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[47829.429623] mmc0: new high speed SDXC card at address 21c9
[47829.433880] Driver 'mmcblk' needs updating - please use bus_type methods
[47829.433944] mmcblk0: mmc0:21c9 APPSD 250 GiB (ro)
[47829.434504]  mmcblk0: p1

Comment: any suggestions??

Comment: helloo?? can someone pls help me with this?