# Can I pull data/open the contents from another HDD using Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, storage, sata

My buddy wants me to extract files out of his dead PC. I don't have one of those SATA to USB cables but what I can do is unplug the CD/DVD drive and plug in the HDD instead (I've used this method to format 2 HDDs before). The only problem is, I just recently started using Ubuntu so I don't exactly know how to open files that are stored in another HDD.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect and mount devices](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285539/detect-and-mount-devices)

Comment: Yes of course. This is why using Linux. It should at least be able to read any common known file system. This is what Windows users can't even imagine. Basic things that work out of the box including cross platform.

Answer (score 3):

You can launch Nautilus (Ubuntu file explorer) to view the device if it is automounted and just copy files from there. 
Otherwise you can try to find the device name with

`sudo fdisk -l`

Then try mounting it with

`sudo mount -t /dev/sdb1 /media`

where `/dev/sdb1` is the name found with `fdisk`