# Nautilus doesn't display the USB flash drive in 'Devices' section

Tags: usb, mount, nautilus

I have read [the topic about similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285539/detect-and-mount-devices). There is answers about how to mount the drive manually (using 'mount' command). Manual mounting works OK but: 1) I forced to enter the correct codepage so non-latin filenames are displayed correctly; 2) it is cumbersome as it relates to all USB drives and Android devices. How do force the user interface to do it's work again? I have Ubuntu 16.04. 'dmesg' commands shows no errors:

```
[ 3241.121059] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3241.121220] scsi host8: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
[ 3242.150166] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 3242.150559] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[ 3242.151149] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 3994624 512-byte logical blocks: (2.05 GB/1.90 GiB)
[ 3242.151760] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 3242.151763] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 3242.152387] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[ 3242.152393] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3242.159983]  sdd: sdd1
[ 3242.162650] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Also, the drive is displayed OK on another PC with Xubuntu 14.04. Also 'Automatic mount' is 'ON' in 'Discs' utility.
UPD:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 1,9 GiB, 2045247488 bytes, 3994624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a4f9c

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *       62 3991931 3991870  1,9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd`

Comment: Done (see UPD section).