# I can't get my computer to detect my external drive

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive

I recently removed the drive from my old laptop and stuck it in an enclosure. My plan was to be able to boot windows on that drive when I wanted to use it. But it didn't boot. So i decided that I could still use it as an external drive. But Ubuntu can't see it either. I tried 'lsusb' 'lsblk' and 'df' none of them can see it at all. I'm still pretty new so I'm sure there's something I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whilst not the accepted answer in this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/285539/detect-and-mount-devices the reply from @αғsнιη seems to match your issue.

Comment: Thank you but this is still not showing the drive. Only the sdaX partitions are shown. The light on the enclosure is hot like it's getting power from the computer, I've double checked that the drive is in correctly, but my computer is just not seeing it :/

Comment: Unlpug your drive. Type `dmesg -w`. Plug your drive in and observe dmesg's output for troubleshooting

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I tried your solution but I'm not sure what I'm looking at. Could you tell me what I should be looking for?

Comment: 1) Unplug your drive. 2) Type `dmesg -w`. 3) plug your drive in (new lines will be created) 4)  copy all new lines 5) edit your question and paste the lines.