# USB not recognized

Tags: usb

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. From a few days ago Verbatim 4G USB is not recognizable. I have two more Verbatim USB 16gb and everything is ok with it. The only USB that can not be recognized is this one with 4gb store. What is the problem? How to fix it, how to make the USB 4gb recognizable?

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary
```

Comment: Plug usb in, run `sudo fdisk -l` and paste output by editing your question

Comment: Zanna thank you for your intervention in the question i post. But i would really like to get an answer considering the not recognizable USB.

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285539/detect-and-mount-devices)

Comment: Emil - what exactly is output? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Output is the result of executed command