# ubuntu detected usb but not showing it

Tags: boot, usb, mount, hard-drive, usb-drive

my usb detected by pc but pc doesn't show it.
other usb work well but this one no.
this usb works but I do not know what I did wrong that the pc did not show it anymore.(I was trying to bootable it to install Windows)
the result of lsblk for usb is (7.2G):
[image]
I think this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285539/detect-and-mount-devices) also had a problem with me, but I can't edit mount option.
i tried to format usb but it doesn't allow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you format a USB stick as a bootable drive, you cannot use it for data storage.

USB sticks come with a FAT partition on them. Put simply, to write a bootable inmage on it, you have to erase that partition.

Comment: I tried to format it but it did not allow.

Comment: The easy way to restore to a regular mass storage device is using the similarly named feature of MKUSB.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Does that just reformat / write another FAT filesystem overtop of the bootable drive. I'll check out the man page and update the answer. Thanks

Comment: @NateT I'm not sure what it does under the hood. I suppose it writes a new partition table then creates and formats a new FAT32 partition.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you aren't running any virtualization software (Like VirtualBox, QEMU, KVM etc.,)

Does this command work (this is just to test if /dev/sdb is writable) ?

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb* ; sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=10 status=progress && sync
```

(This command overwrites /dev/sdb ; beware not to overwrite important storage media)

If it works, open GParted, then select the device, create a new "msdos" partition table, then reboot and format with GNOME disks.

If it doesn't work, please post the error messages.

Comment: it says "umount: /dev/sdb: not mounted." usb doesn't have any partition and can't be mounted.I made a partition once and mounted it, and it was empty, but I could not copy anything on it.I deleted the partition and tried to install it again, which gave this error:"input/output error during write on /dev/sdb gparted"