# Disable discovery or listing of HDD partitions

Tags: nautilus, system, administration

I would like to disable auto detection or listing of certain partitions in applications such as Nautilus. I have a HP laptop that contains a recovery partition along with a EFI partition and I would like to hide/disable them so they are not visible to any Ubuntu user to prevent accidentally changing these. Can this be done?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-my-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527), it might help you edit the mount options.

Comment: Mitch, This will work just fine! I just added additional authorization to mount the partitions... Thanks Allot!

Comment: Good, I'm glad it helped.  If the answer was satisfactory, you may up-vote it if feel it worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the user privileges and revoke the right to mount filesystems. Take a look at "System settings -> user management -> edit user" or something similar on your system.

A more radical approach is to use GParted and enable the "hidden" flag for the partitions you wish to hide. **BE WARNED** that this will also hide them from the boot process - the partitions will be completely hidden from your system. Also, if the boot-loader is installed on one of these partitions you will have to move it to be able to boot. In other words, use this method only if you don't care about dual-booting.

Comment: hmayag, thank you for the answer, I still want to dual boot so second option will not work. The only problem I see with revoking the right to mount file systems is this would also prevent the user from mounting CDROMS, USB Drives etc... is there a way that you know of through maybe fstab or something similar to just revoke permissions on a certain partition?

Comment: I suppose you could mount the said partitions with noauto option, witch means that they will not be mounted automatically at boot time. This though does not prohibit mounting them manually after boot. I'm no expert on this, so I suggest you take a look at [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) Perhaps a combination of options will achieve what you are looking for. I hope this helps.