# External Hard Drive Won't Mount But Is Detected

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

Yesterday I bought an external drive and after reformatting it to ext4, Ubuntu could no longer "see" it. I [asked for help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302480/cant-mount-external-drive-after-reformatting), and eventually came to the conclusion that the drive was somewhat defective. So I returned it, and got a new one. Before reformatting it, I plugged it and discovered that Ubuntu (12.04) couldn't see it. I thought maybe I'd goofed up something in the OS, so I used my 32GB thumbdrive to back up my docs & needed files, and then installed Ubuntu (13.04) from scratch.

When I plugged in my external drive, *the new OS still can't see it* there. I ran some checks, and saw the output of `dmesg` actually does show it was detected, but otherwise there was NO sign of it in any other way.

**How do I fix this? Is there a way to mount it even if I can't "see" it there?**

Here's the output messages from a few things I checked this evening after I installed 13.04 & plugged in my external drive....

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000539fb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   969058303   484528128   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       969060350   976771071     3855361    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       969060352   976771071     3855360   82  Linux swap / Solaris


$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b209 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
```

---- after plugging in my 32GB thumbdrive ----

```
$ dmesg | tail -n 17

[  979.174904] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  979.267866] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5530
[  979.267874] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  979.267879] usb 2-1.1: Product: Cruzer Glide
[  979.267884] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[  979.267889] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 200549636207BE00F894
[  979.268934] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[  980.267711] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Glide     1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  980.268959] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  980.270467] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 62530624 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 GB/29.8 GiB)
[  980.274744] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  980.274753] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  980.275724] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  980.285663]  sdb: sdb1
[  980.289108] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  980.762302] systemd-hostnamed[3676]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 1083.401263] sdb: detected capacity change from 32015679488 to 0
[ 1246.785895] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
```

---- after plugging in my 2TB Toshiba Canvio external hard drive & then unplugged it ----

```
$ dmesg | tail -n 8

[ 1728.251102] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 1728.345301] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=d010
[ 1728.345309] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1728.345314] usb 2-1.3: Product: External USB 3.0
[ 1728.345319] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Toshiba
[ 1728.345324] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 20130114021358
[ 1728.346698] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[ 1729.423255] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 8
```

...as you can see, it's detected it, but I don't know how to access it or mount it. I can see that the 32GB thumbdrive was mounted automatically to sdb, but the external drive was simply detected and that's all. They were both plugged into the same USB port.

Comment: Is the HDD formatted ans has a valid partition?

Comment: Yes. I hooked it up to Windows 8, and I can read & write files. It works via Windows 7 too. So I know the drive is fine.

Comment: It seems this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/530000/usb-3-0-port-not-detecting-usb-modem may solve the problem.  It did for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say it works in Windows 8, is that using the same hardware and port?

With the "disconnect" message ~1100ms after insertion, I wonder if the USB port doesn't have quite enough power for the drive.

See this article from Toshiba: http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Drivers-and-Utilities-Knowledge/External-USB-3-0-Hard-Drive-not-recognized/ta-p/379941

Comment: Oh wow, that answers a lot of mysteries. It looks like I need to get a different cable for this to work. Thanks! I was going bananas trying to figure out what I did wrong.