# USB 3.0 port not detecting USB modem

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem, modem

I have HP 250 G2 laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 (dual-boot).
The laptop has USB 2.0 ports and one USB 3.0 port.

I am using USB 3G mobile broadband modem (Huawei K4201), which is working perfectly on 2.0 ports, but is not being detected on 3.0 port. Strangely other devices (mouse, USB drive …) have no problems with that USB 3.0 port.

I would like to use modem on 3.0 port, because its on left side of the laptop and it is not in the way of mouse movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf` file.

At the end you will find:

```
# Optional increase of "delay_use" for the usb-storage driver; there are hints
# that a recent kernel default change to 1 sec. may lead to problems, particu-
# larly with USB 3.0 ports. Set this to at least 3 (seconds) in that case.
# Does nothing if the current system value is same or higher

SetStorageDelay=3
```

Try 3 or 5 seconds here.

Comment: Default setting was 4 seconds. I tried with 3 seconds and now its working perfectly. Thank you :)

Comment: I figured that value 2 works best in my case.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer works for my question http://askubuntu.com/questions/701132/usb-3g-modem-initialization-unstable as well!

Comment: does this require rebooting to take effect?