# Ubuntu 12.10 wont mount an External harddrive

Tags: 12.10, hard-drive, automount

I have 2 external 1TB harddrives, both of which normally get mounted on startup. For the past couple of days, one of these drives has not been mounted. I have tried unplugged and plugging the non-mounted one, aswell as restarting the system. But this has not fixed the problem.

Is there anyway of forcing Ubuntu to mount anything plugged into the PC, or anything similar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527), and see if it might help.

Answer (score 0):

There sure is!  Use the mount command to force it to mount, and umount to un-mount it when you are done and if you decide that you want it un-mounted.