# Installation - running out of space on the primary hdd can seem the system to find the second hdd?

Tags: installation

I have secondly 6gb installed into the system with nothing on it. I would like to utilize with the primary but can't seem to figure out what I need to do in fstab.  I'm sure it something to do with a mount but am lost.

Any assistance would appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

To mount a Hard Drive, it can be done either using terminal, or GUI.  To use terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdax /mntpoint
```

Just replace the X in `/sdax` with you drive's ID, and replace `/mntpoint` with the name that you want.  To find out your ID, type `sudo fdisk -l`

[image]

To use GUI, just type Disks in Dash, and when it open up. click on the little right arrow.
[image]

Or look at this [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527), to have the drive mount automatically.