# Auto mount a drive that located on Ubuntu and auto share that drive for Window

Tags: mount

I have tried to find the solution for many days but I couldn't find one.
All are posted about auto mount a share folder that come from Window.
But my case the backup drive is located on Ubuntu 12.04 desktop and I would like to have my drive (/dev/sda3) mount at boot time then auto share that drive for accessing from Window users. Could you please help me!

Comment: Take a look at My answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527) for Auto mounting, and then look at [Mount Windows Shares Permanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

Answer (score 1):

I divide it into two parts:

```
1). Mount the drive at boot time:
    * sudo vi /etc/fstab
    * then add this line:  /dev/sda3    /media/lnxBackUp  ext4  users,user      0  0
      In my case, sda3 is the drive that I would like to mount and ext4 is the partition of sda3.

2). Install samba server:
    * sudo apt-get install samba
    * sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
      then edit its config file by adding these information at the end of the page:
    [lnxBackUp]
          writable = yes
          path = /media/lnxBackUp
          guest ok = yes
          create mask = 0777
          comment = Backup drive
          directory mask = 0777
    * Create a folder in /media
    * sudo mkdir /medir/lnxBackUp
    * sudo mount -a
```

Now, you can access a drive shared (lnxBackUp) from Window.

cheers