# Best way to automatically mount and share USB drives in Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: usb, mount, samba, automatic

I'd like to find a way to automatically mount any external usb drive connected to my server, and then to automatically share it via samba.
The main thing that confuses me is how to handle unmounting it before it is unplugged without having to fire up a command line.
The USB drives will also be used in Windows environments and will therefore be FAT or NTFS formatted.

For reasons I won't go into, my family has a number of laptops with no access to USB ports. I'm just trying to create a simple way for them to be able to plug a USB pen into my server, access a samba share to throw on a couple of work/college assignments etc, and then unplug. Ideally, this needs to happen without me having to ssh into my server every time.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry no one has answered this for you - [this entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305833/auto-mount-a-drive-that-located-on-ubuntu-and-auto-share-that-drive-for-window) describes a process similar to what you are looking for.