# How to add ODD to "Devices" in File System?

Tags: hardware

How can you add a DVD+/-RW disk drive to devices under file system?
Do you need to mount it first?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the drive mounted, in order to show up in the side panel.

[image]

The best way to to have the drive auto mount that way you don't have to mount it every time.  To have drives mount automatically, see this [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527).

Comment: I can do that for my hard disk, but when I try for my ODD, I can't click there. I can only click "Create disk image..." and "Benchmark Volume".