# Binding a partition or drive after fstab

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I have modified the fstab to automatically mount a partition and set up an aufs on a read-only filesystem and a folder in partition. But somehow in the boot up, I saw that it couldn't find the folder in that partition. I have certain programs that start on boot up and it requires the aufs filesystem. I was wondering if there is a way of mounting after fstab.

Comment: Does [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527), help?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by creating an init script that will run at the begining of the init or upstart. I have to create a file in `/etc/rc2.d/` and name it like this : `S(number){name}` where (number) determine the order of the execution o the script and {name} is the name of the script. Assigning a small value on {number} means it is going to be executed before the other scripts that have a higher {number}. Simply editing `/etc/rc.local`  have a 15% chance it will work because it will run **AFTER** each run level .

What I do : I simply change the number of the filename of this file: `S99rc.local` which is located at `/etc/rc2.d/` to `S10.rc.local` and I write the mount commands in `/etc/rc.local` file.