# Change Apache document root folder to secondary hard drive

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

I installed the ubuntu 12.04 server edition for my server pc . i had installed lamp server. i need to change the var/www location to my secondary hard disk location. i was configured so many time to at gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default here is my code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    #DocumentRoot /var/www
    DocumentRoot /media/myserver/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    #<Directory /var/www/>
        <Directory /media/myserver/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and also used

```
sudo chown -R var/www /media/myserver/
```

and

```
chmod -R 755 /media/myserver/
```

still i was not able to connect my /media/myserver and my browser show the following message

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Please tell anyone how to mount myserver at my var/www, thanks advance

Comment: was the second drive formatted and mounted to the  /media/myserver directory? did you add a fstab entry for that drive ?

Comment: Have you checked whether the trailing slash on the document root is the problem, notice where its commented out there isnt one, but on your edit, there is.

Comment: Did you try changing apache2.conf file ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You'll have to edit `apache2.conf` and `000-default.conf` to change the document root of apache.

The Apache server is installed on `/var/www/html`.This is the default root directory of apache.

Either change the root directory of Apache or move the project to `/var/www/html`.

1. To change Apache's root directory, run:

   ```
    cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
   ```
2. Then open the `000-default.conf` file using the command:

   ```
    nano 000-default.conf
   ```
3. Edit the `DocumentRoot` option:

   ```
    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/project
   ```
4. Then restart the apache server:

   ```
    sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

---

If you get `Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server` after changing the root of apache then do follow these steps

1. Find the `apache2.conf` located in `/etc/apache2` and open it using:

   ```
    nano apache2.conf
   ```
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and search for Directory (It should be in line 153)
3. It should look like this

   ```
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
   ```
4. Change it to

   ```
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
   ```
5. Restart apache

   ```
    sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

---

I made a script that changes apache root in a single command. You can find it on my [github](https://github.com/hsb4995/Apachange).

Comment: It is kind of work for me but I have to add `<Directory /path/to/my/project>Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>`. In `/etc/apache2/apahce2.conf` before restarting the apache2 service.

Comment: This works in 20.04, Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

Maybe a little bit late. But still..

You should edit your directory permissions in apache.conf under /etc/apache2

Search for this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and add this code under of it, which gives the permission to access your directory

```
 <Directory /media/myserver/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply change the document root in your activated configuration. `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`  and then Make sure reloading your apache.

So try with this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /media/myserver/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /media/myserver/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the proper permission should be given like this:

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/myserver/
sudo chmod -R g+rw /media/myserver/
```

Comment: yes my friend i was done this already . see the above code i was comment the default document root and inserted new document root. after apache2 stop and start. it's not worked. it's 403 error, and showed permission access denied and my browser

Comment: Have you seen my last edite?

Comment: yes i saw this. still it's show you dont have permission to access /on this server

Comment: error when running httpd.exe: `Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Answer (score 4):

1. you modify `apache2.conf`. Replace `/var/www/` with `/your/path`:

   ```
   <Directory /your/path/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
2. Modify the `000-default.conf` file:

   ```
   DocumentRoot /your/path/
   ```
3. Change the ownership of the directories to yourself from file manager or terminal (e.g. `sudo chown pi: path`). Without this you will get this error message:

   ```
   You don't have permission to access / on this server.
   ```

Answer (score 2):

As a quick workaround (safe and quick) you can make the mounting point of your external hard driver to the default root directory ( /var/www by default).

Assigning the mounting point to a per-existing directory is safe but the old content can't be reached unless you unmounted the driver.

To learn more how to create a mounting point refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically).

Comment: According to that idea I would mount certain folder, by using `bindfs`, as it is described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1024308/566421

Answer (score 1):

`sudo gedit etc/apache2/apache2.conf` 
add this
 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

in virtual configuration :`/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf`

```
ServerAdmin anilrmg@localhost.com
ServerName anilrmg.localhost.com
ServerAlias www.anilrmg.localhost.com
DocumentRoot /home/anilrmg/projects/code/anilrmg
```

`sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`

Answer (score 1):

For those who use VirtualBox guest additions and get `you don't have permission to access /on this server` despite of everything mentioned above:

If you are trying to set the Apache document root folder to a VirtualBox shared folder,and you have tried everything above and that did not help, there is one more step.

In short, the solution is to add user 'www-data' to the group 'vboxsf':

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf www-data
```

You can not change the owner and/or the group of the VirtualBox shared folder, but the solution above worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make sure the whole path was granted Apache.

```
chown www-data /media;
chown www-data /media/MNT/;
chown www-data /media/MNT/DISK;
chown www-data /media/MNT/DISK/www-root;
```