# Change directory of Ubuntu www web server?

Tags: php, www, magento

I'm wondering if I can change the root directory of an Ubuntu web server from:

```
/var/www/html
```

to:

```
/home/Janderson/magento
```

How would I do this? I want to access Magento when I go to localhost in my web browser, and not anything else.

This is **not** a production environment, it's a local development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Actually ubuntu does not have a defult web folder.

`/var/www/html` is your web servers default path.
If  you are using LAMP stack your webserver is apache so you need to go to apache's defaut settings and change your webserver path there.

Check this for detailed instructions on how to do so:

[How To Move an Apache Web Root to a New Location on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-an-apache-web-root-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I saw this link earlier and it looks good. This question might get closed as a duplicate. You may want to add your answer on the [original quesiton](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337874/change-apache-document-root-folder-to-secondary-hard-drive)