# Auto mount server Secondary hard disk shared folder to client

Tags: server, mount, samba, fstab, automount

I was tried to Mount server secondary hard disk shared folder to my client computer. Already the secondary share folder was mound on server like this

> /media/sdc1/foldername/

i want to auto mount above share folder to my client computer when start.

The following code was written on /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.1.150/media/sdc1/HTTPServer     /media/HTTPServer     ntfs-3g     defaults,locale=en_US.utf8   0    0
```

it's does not work and it's return the following error

```
mount: only root can mount //192.168.1.150/media/sdc1/HTTPServer on /media/HTTPServer
```

i was tried to share from ubuntu 12.04 server to ubuntu 13.04 client pc. i was installed samba file share server on server pc. it's work fine for windows os share. but i need ubuntu auto-mount share . i was read so many article for this issues. But i did not get correct please tell anyone. thanks advance

Comment: Does [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527)help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that you have tried to mount network share with ntfs filesystem, right? Have you tried to mount it using `mount.cifs` or `smbfs`? Or even your share has another filesystem it shoud use `smbfs` not `ntfs-3g` I think.

Could you please provide `mount -v | grep $foldername` output for already mounted share?

And part of samba.conf fot this share from server computer.

Comment: yes i was tried mount.cifs and smbfs also no use. then mount -v | grep $foldername return nothing .

Comment: $foldername means name of your folder under which your share already mounted ($ is a symbol for shell variables). Could you please provide command you used to mount folder directly from cli?

Comment: and could you please provide /etc/samba/smb.conf content.

Comment: hm, I'm just curious - have you used sudo to do mount command? As I see you receive this error from CLI, not from logs.

Comment: No i did not used sudo for mount on etc/fstab

Comment: Hm, if you run mount command from ordinary user (who hasn't superuser rights) it will fails. Please try to mount this share using sudo. It works with the following way `sudo $your-command`

Comment: Am i do this in etc/fstab

Comment: No, it needed only for direct command, to mount shares which has entries in /etc/fstab you need to do `sudo mount /media/HTTPServer` particularly for your directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10406/discussion-between-svyatoslav-and-tamil-arvu)