# What is arios-automount startup command?

Tags: 12.04

I accidentally removed arios-automount startup, so drives don't startup with the system any more, even with reinstalling the program, and i don't know the startup command for it.
Any Help?

Comment: Try this.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the command for the *arios-automount* package should be **"automount"**

Make sure you have installed the package, there is a file name **"automount.desktop"** in the `/etc/xdg/autostart` or in  `~/.config/autostart/` folder with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
# @location ~/.config/autostart/
Name=Auto-mount
Type=Application
Exec=automount
Icon=gnome-dev-harddisk
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true

Comment[en_US]=Automatically Mounts Partitions
Comment=Automatically Mounts Partitions
```

If you want to add this command to the startup list, open the *Startup Applications* from the dash.

[image]

Add the following:

[image]

```
Name: Auto-mount
Command: automount
Comment: Automatically Mounts Partitions
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even you have installed the Arios application , you have to set the application to be in startup list. I mean you have to add it to startup list.

To add it to the startup list, Open your Unity dash and type as "startup" and it will list the application click to open it and then click at add . it will open the window and from there click at your file system and then choose usr/bin path as shown in the below image.

Then select the arios app and add it. you are done.

[image]