# Folder links not working after reboot

Tags: shortcuts

I want to create a link (like shortcut in windows) to a folder stored in one of my drives. I right click on the folder and select make link. Then I cut and paste this link to the desktop. It works fine in the same session but when I reboot and try to open the link, it says this link is broken.

The drive is of NTFS format which I use when using windows.

I'll furnish any additional details if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your folder is on a NTFS drive, you have to mount first that drive in order to be accessible. See this answer to know how to do it:

- [How to auto mount NTFS part/disks in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/300426/147044).