# Making a link to a folder on windows?

Tags: partitioning, windows, directory

sorry but I am just very new to ubuntu and i can't get the answer via search or google, because there are too many options and nothing seems to help me with my problem.

I have one hard disk in my small notebook. I've made a new partition to install Linux and I can still open my folders on C:/, where windows is actually installed.

Now i want to make a link on my desktop for example from my music folder from windows.
How can i do that? I tried some ways, but after a reboot the system always claims that the link doesnt work anymore.

What can i do?
Thx

Comment: try this... it works perfectly for me
http://askubuntu.com/questions/739400/create-a-link-to-a-folder-in-windows-partition

Answer (score 0):

The link doesn't work anymore after a system reboot because you have to mount again the drive C:/ after start up. When you open the drive C:/ from inside of nautilus for example, this it automatically mounts it and your link will work again.

To make it to be mounted automatically see at start up [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/271527/147044).

Answer (score 0):

For linking folders on Windows to the Ubuntu subsystem use:

```
ln -s windowsPath linuxPath
```