# Show Ubuntu operating system details in Dell 15 3521 laptop

Tags: software-recommendation, dell

I have purchased a new Dell 15 3521 Pentium dual core 3rd generation laptop having Ubuntu. I am unable to see information about system properties like installed memory (RAM), processor, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Sysinfo (*sysinfo*) from the default Ubuntu repositories. Sysinfo is a graphical tool that is able to display some hardware and  software information about the computer it is run on.

It is able to recognize information about:

- System (Linux distribution release, versions of GNOME, kernel, gcc and
  Xorg and hostname)
- CPU (vendor identification, model name, frequency, level2 cache, bogomips,
  model numbers and flags)
- Memory (total system RAM, free memory, swap space total and free, cached,
  active, inactive memory)
- Storage (IDE interface, all IDE devices, SCSI devices)
- Hardware (motherboard, graphic card, sound card, network devices)
- NVIDIA graphic card: only with NVIDIA display driver installed

[image]

In Ubuntu 20.04 and later install System Profiler ( `sudo apt install hardinfo` ) instead of Sysinfo.

[image]

Cheese (*cheese*) is a tool to take pictures and videos from your webcam. Cheese can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.

The latest version of Ubuntu is Ubuntu 13.10. The next long term support version of Ubuntu is Ubuntu 14.04, which will be released in April of this year. Ubuntu 13.10 can be upgraded directly to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks Karel for your information, kindly can you tell me how to install sysinfo to check further details as you mentioned - Srinath

Comment: From the terminal run `sudo apt-get install sysinfo` or else you can install Sysinfo from the Ubuntu Software Center. Not much else I can add, except that Sysinfo is a graphical application, so when you open it you will see that everything is there so it's easy to find whatever you are looking for.

Comment: Karel, as you said installed sysinfo from the Ubuntu Software Center. Now how to view required details as I am unable to view same

Comment: And how to upgrade version from 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04.. how much time/MB requires to do this as I was using 1GB 3G within some time all data consumed with nil & not aware how much data consumption/time for version change. Kindly reply. Thanks

Comment: 1. Search for _Sysinfo_ in the Dash, click the Sysinfo icon and then do like it shows in my screenshot. 2. Ubuntu 13.04 will be End of Life in just 11 more days, so don't upgrade to 13.04!!! Wait until April and upgrade directly to Ubuntu 14.04, another Long Term Support release. An upgrade will probably eat about 600-800MB of data including all the application package updates. It's too bad that you have to pay for 3G, that sounds expensive.

Comment: Hi Karel, As you said in 2. point directly upgrade to 14.04 which comes in April, i read in some comments that don't upgrade directly to 14.04, upgrade from step by step. i.e. currently i have 12.04 LT version, upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 then from 12.10 to 13.04.. till current version, any harm if upgrade directly from 12.04 LT version to 14.04 LT version in coming April month. Kindly clarify

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is a Long Term Support (LTS) release. Ubuntu 14.04 is also a Long Term Support release. You can upgrade **directly** from a Long Term Support release to the next Long Term Support release.

Comment: Thanks Karel for your quick response, kindly tell me in between 12.04 & 14.04 (LTS) there is 13.04 Long Term Support(LTS) also which can be crossed & upgrade directly to 14.04 Long Term Support without 13.04 LTS

Comment: Hi Karel, can you tell me where to give accept vote to you for all above support

Comment: Hi Karel, can I know what is Ubuntu & Xubuntu, difference of both.

Comment: You may mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it, which will make its color change to green. Xubuntu is a derivative of Ubuntu that is designed to run on older, less powerful computers, comparable to Windows Vista in look and feel. Lubuntu is even more lightweight, comparable to Windows XP in look and feel.

Comment: As per your info clicked gray check mark above left side & turned to green color, hope this received as Vote / accepted from me to you. thank you for your support

Comment: Karel, I was using internet access thru wifi hotspot from tablet to laptop, now i want to have internet connection from laptop to tablet, how can i do that, kindly confirm

Comment: Some tablets do not support ad hoc network, only wifi hotspot (access point mode), so start off with the answers to this question: [How to setup a wi-fi hotspot (access point mode)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode), especially the answer by Web-E.

Comment: Hi Karel, whatever I am saving on desktop, i am not able to view in next login, can I know on this & please confirm me where are drives (C:& D:) available. Thanks

Comment: @user234466 This question didn't get the most votes, but I like the answers better for you because it is recent and it is the easiest one to understand (there are lots of screenshots): [Is there a program to mount all of my drives automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically). Try saving your files by category in the folders you already have in /home: Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any additional software to know your system properties. 
To find out ram amount you can open terminal by `alt+t` and type:

```
free -m
```

and then pressing enter. to find out other information you can use other commands.
To view all information about your system in terminal you can also install `neofetch`
by:

```
sudo apt install neofetch
```

and running it by:

```
neofetch
```

To find out latest Ubuntu OS you should know that each year there is 2 Ubuntu releases;one in 4th and the other in 10th month of the year. Currently latest Ubuntu release is 19.04 .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SystemMonitor? As far i know it comes installed by default but if it's not installed try:

> 1- Open your terminal (ctrl+alt+t);
>
> 2- type: sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor;
>
> 3- type your password;

Comment: Thank you Eddie got it thru default system monitor. I am able to see processor as Intel Pentium but my laptop is with Pentium dual core 3rd generation. How to check this. Thanks, Kindly reply

Answer (score 0):

@Srinath

There is a detailed article on the subject at this link. http://www.linuxandlife.com/2011/11/how-to-check-hardware-specification-in.html  .

However you can use this command at the terminal

sudo lshw -short