# Steam forgets where game directory is on second HDD

Tags: 13.10, hard-drive, games, ssd, steam

I installed steam onto my SSD, but of course that can't hold very many games so I setup a second steam directory on my HDD.

However every single time a I restart my computer steam shows all my games in the directory as being uninstalled. However, when I click install I can navigate to the directory I made, select it, then all my steam games once again appear as installed.

How do I fix this.

Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

When ubuntu starts up it only mounts the partitions that it needs. Because your HDD is a seperate partition, it is not mounted on boot. This means that any program on your Ubuntu installation that uses a directory on your HDD will not be able to find it. For example, My music player's library is on my Windows partition. Unless I mount the windows partition, I will not see my songs.

You can automatically mount this on boot. [Here is a guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically)

Comment: Whenever I follow the instructions this happens: Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/4d76dc02-f9a4-4790-a68b-930e9bc5ffef"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

 (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Comment: Alright that error doesn't appear anymore, but I have tried quite a few different combinations of settings with the disk and it changes nothing.