# Trouble with sharing

Tags: system-installation, mount, sharing

I am trying to create a file server / backup machine out of an old pc and am not having any luck sharing the intended drive with the network.

Please have a little patience with my ignorance, I happily to confess to being a complete newbie (only experience is a couple of weeks trying to get this to work)

I have in a pc with internal drives
1* small SSD for OS
1* 1TB HDD for serving files - to be shared
1* 2TB HDD for backup of the 1TB HDD

I have already tried everything I can find on this forum and others, but still can't mount both hdds where I want them, and still have only ever successfully shared /home/ (but never when I have mounted the required drive there.)

So here's the question. Is there a user guide somewhere which can explain this for a novice? Bearing in mind that I am performing a clean install. (tried both 12.04 and 13.10)

I have tried mounting on install, using pysdm and directly in fstab with UUID.
I have tried sharing directly from folder, using CLI and from GUI Samba.

~ DazedandConfused

Comment: Samba is a PITA on Linux. Sometimes it just works out of the box. In other times it stubbornly refuses to work until you've done a lot of configuring.  Why not use something else, like OwnCloud? You can use it in a local network. Or just run an SSH service on the file/backup server, connect to it from your other machines and save that connection so it's easy to access. Yes, you may need other 3rd party programs but if your other machines are on Linux too, many file browsers have the feature to connect to other servers built-in. That is what I usually do.

Comment: I think there are two separate issues here: mounting the drives where you want them, and sharing them over the network. Do step 1 first. You want to try the mount command in a terminal until it works, i.e. until you can access the files on the hdd from the desired directory. Then, you want to edit /etc/fstab to have the hdd mounted automatically at the next reboot. When that works, try to share it using Samba.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting disk through terminal read up here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount - and here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

For a friendlier way - [Is there a program to mount all of my drives automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically)

As for Samba, I suggest you consider other options as well like in my comment above. This file/backup server will be up and running 99% of the time? Download Samba package from the repo, run the service. Many times it works for me without configuring anything. Just right click on the folder then find the Sharing options.

Try reading up here - http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/ - and here - https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html