# Auto mount mount point on iSCSI driver

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, automatic, iscsi

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I recently added a 1 terabyte iSCSI volume with a single ext4 partition. Everything works as it should but with the only issue being I cannot create a mount point using fstab with a UUID line. I can mount the mount point manually but it wont mount a boot time. The boot process stops and displays a message like "The disk drive for /images is not ready yet or not present." Is there some way to delay the mounting of the mount point until after the drive becomes available?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem in your case is that you are trying to mount a remote device before the network has finished coming up.  You should add the _netdev option to /etc/fstab for the iSCSI device to make it wait to mount until the network is up.