# Desktop link to file on second hard drive broken after reboot

Tags: symbolic-link, persistence

I'm using a second hard drive to hold most of my data files.  Links to files and folders on the second drive from all locations on my first drive, where Ubuntu 14.04 is installed, work, except that after a reboot links on the desktop are broken.  Links in my Home folder remain valid, which is strange since the Desktop is a sub-folder of my Home folder.  I mount the second drive in the Startup Applications app.

This is different behaviour from 13.10 (and older releases) where the Desktop links persisted after reboots.

Comment: Check this
http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/300426#300426

Answer (score 1):

I think its mount problem if you have to mount the second hard drive at each restart it, the symbolic links will surely be broken to avoid that simply edit

```
/etc/rc.local
```

add mount command to the second hard drive to it.

if problem persists add the symbolic link commands in the file also so it would be created at each restart.

Comment: My question is more specific---why do links in Trusty on the Desktop not persist while links in other folders do? I know that if the second drive is not mounted at startup in some way no links will persist.  Mounting the drive in fstab is one method that works, but I wanted to use the Startup Applications method and I can guess it has something to do with what order things are done during startup, but exactly how is what I am curious about.

Comment: Hi, sorry for such a n00b question, how do you "add mount command to the second hard drive to it"....thx ;)