# How do I automount partitions on statup, Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, automount

Recently, I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to Xubuntu 14.04.

I have 2 partitions on my computer: One for Windows and one for Ubuntu. I keep all my music and junk on the Windows partition, so when I click on Clementine, I have to click on my windows partition for Clementine to find the song.

I remember I installed some program in 12.04 that automatically mounted partitions, but I can't find it again.

It turned the path to the partition from something like this `/media/169821DE9821BD5D/` to something like this `/media/sda1`.

Anybody know what it is? I just spent the last half hour looking up ways to automount, but none of them was woking with xubuntu. Any help?

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically

Comment: basically that goes over everything you need to do from what I see, could you put that as a possible answer @muru ?

Comment: @sbergeron should I put it as answer or mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: not really a duplicate question, even though the answer there is absolutely perfect for here, I say put up the link then quote the answer

Answer (score 7):

From Ubuntu 12.10 onwards, the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/271527/158442) applies for automounting partitions. The Disks utility (formerly `palimpsest`) (which is already installed on Ubuntu, but perhaps not on Xubuntu) should be enough. If it isn't installed, click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-disk-utility) to install it, or use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

Open it, select your disk and partition, and click on the gear icon to get to mount options and enable automount. Screenshots are available in the linked answer.

Comment: Your link where you wrote "this answer" above doesn't seem to be the right link at all. Perhaps this is the link you meant to post in its place? http://askubuntu.com/questions/783061/automount-in-16-04

Comment: @GabrielStaples no, my comment on the question has the correct link. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make the directory to mount to (e.g.) `/mnt/2tb` and then you can edit `/etc/fstab` to create the mount. Fstab will then automatically mount your drive/partition to the directory created at boot.

Answer (score 0):

All info above is good - but this is the EASIEST

- Use the "Disks" application. If you don't have it, you can install it with `sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility`
- click on the partition you need to auto mount,
- click on the little cog wheel [Settings Icon] - for Additional partition options.
- then Edit Mount Options as you need

1- Toggle 'Automatic mount option'
2- Check 'mount at startup' option
3- Change other settings if you need

[image: Disks Application Image]

[image: Mount Options Window Image]

[copied from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/848542/370087) answer]

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use `/etc/fstab` file to create a mount even after reboots:
The syntax to be followed in /etc/fstab is:

```
from              to          ext      defaults              0      0
/var/www/abc     /home/abc    ext      defaults              0      0
```

This mounts `/var/www/abc` to `/home/abc`.

details of using /etc/fstab file can be found  [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab)