# How to make partitions mount at startup in Ubuntu gnome 16.04?

Tags: partitioning, gnome, 16.04, automount

How do you make windows partitions mount at startup with the ubuntu system? 
I always keep my media and data files on windows partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your options to mount partitions are covered in [this page.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

Ensure you use the UUID for your drive, as directed in the linked page.

**Edit:** As noted by another member, do not mount your Windows partition that has your OS on it as RW, make sure it's Read-Only!  Other partitions that are only used as storage can be Read/Write.  I had originally assumed you meant storage drives, not OS drives.  Edited for clarity.

Comment: Often best not to directly mount the Windows system partition read/write. The Linux NTFS driver exposes all the files & folders that Windows normally keeps hidden to avoid user errors or corruption. Best to use a separate NTFS shared data partition and set Windows system partition read only (ro) or mount and hide mount so not seen at all normally. https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: True, but the question was "windows partitionS", plural, so I assume NTFS partitions and not necessarily the Windows System/OS partition.  I will however update my answer to specify this, thanks for pointing out, and, +1

Comment: Editing FSTab is very dangerous.  One minor misspell, and your Raspberry Pi can become unbootable.

Comment: @IgorG. Of course, but so are most things in Linux.  Doesn't take much to kill a system, even by accident.  But then you get to learn how to fix it.  Welcome to Linux :)

Answer (score 6):

All info above is good - but this is the EASIEST

Use the Disks application - already part of Ubuntu 14.04/16/04, click on the partition, click on the little cog wheel under - for settings. And then Edit Mount Options

- change settings to NOT start automatically
- mount at startup

Comment: it works! On practice it adds to end of /etc/fstab following line `/dev/disk/by-uuid/<my uuid> /home auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0`