# No accees to HD from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade

I made a recent upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.
When in 14.04 I could easily access another HD on my pc where I store all my media.Now from 16.04 I can't see the HD on the launcher as before.
Can someone please tell me if this is normal ??

Comment: take a look at [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783061/automount-in-16-04) what happened when you active auto-mount on that disk?

Comment: I don't know what launcher you mean, what program it's in, or what desktop / Ubuntu you're using, but maybe it's just not showing the shortcuts, or the program has changed. Could try running `lsblk` in a terminal to see if the drive's still recognized, or use Disks (gnome-disk-utility).

Comment: Launcher =desktop launcher

Comment: Hi Xen2050:I tried to follow the instructions of the post you pointed  me but when I come to ; "edit partition" I get the following message:" no support for modifying a partition a table of type (null)' (udisks-error-quark, 11).What does this means ??

Comment: sorry on my last post I was answering to Yaron not xen2050.

Comment: no one ???There's no solution for this problem ???@Yaron

Comment: No solution for this  problem ???