# How to Ignore encrypted (LUKS) on external hard drive

Tags: 16.04, luks, storage, cryptsetup

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (which is upgraded from 14.04).

I have created a LUKS volume with `cryptsetup` on my external harddrive.

The problem is, everytime I connect the harddrive, ubuntu prompts me for a passphrase. I believe this is normal behaviour. The prompt is as follows

[image: Ubuntu prompts passphrase to unlock volume]

But, I need to disable this behaviour, I don't want ubuntu to ask me password, NOR i want to put the password on some file.

How can I tell ubuntu to ignore the LUKS encrypted harddrive ?
I want to connect the drive, ubuntu keep quiet, and I will mount the drive myself, ie with `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdX`.

I have tried to put `rd.luks=0` at boot parameter, but it doesn't works.
And please, the solutions should allow ubuntu to automount non-encrypted drive.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please reconcile the statements " I will mount the drive myself" and  " the solutions should allow ubuntu to automount non-encrypted drive" . In addition, if the drive automounts, what is the point of encryption ? Sounds as if you want the "Remember Forever" option ?

Comment: I simply want ubuntu to ignore the encrypted volume until I spesifically run the command to mount it. I am thinking of disabling auto-mount on external storage to achieve this, but i need to automount on normal non-encrypted disk. And no, i don't want the "remember forever" option, furthermore, i don't want any trace of passphrase for the disk.

Comment: As far as I know you have to add an entry in fstab for the crypt = https://askubuntu.com/questions/783061/automount-in-16-04

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Fstab entry is for internal drive, while in my case, is for external drive, hot-plugged via usb.

Comment: Post your fstab entery for your crypt.