# /dev/sda2 disappears appear Ubuntu reboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

After rebooting my Ubuntu 16.04 on virtual machine, I discovered that /dev/sda2 is no longer available.

Here are my outputs from df and sudo fdisk -l:

df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            121G     0  121G   0% /dev
tmpfs            25G   13M   25G   1% /run
/dev/sda5       769G  423G  307G  58% /
tmpfs           121G   25M  121G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           121G     0  121G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            25G   56K   25G   1% /run/user/100
```

sudo fdisk -l:

```
Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624 4621869402 4620818779   2.2T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  6258690048 6291453951   32763904  15.6G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  4621871104 4621873151       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda5  4621873152 6258690047 1636816896 780.5G Linux filesystem
```

How can I remount the /dev/sda2? Thanks

Comment: Are there an entry for /dev/sda2 in /etc/fstab ?

Comment: I issued this command: less /etc/fstab | grep sda2. It returned nothing.

Comment: @RobJohn Entries in fstab usually go by UUID. Look at it again without grep (  you shou be using `grep 'pattern' file` syntax, anyway ).  Has there been any update prior to reboot ?

Comment: Thanks @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy  I have checked again as you suggested, there is  no /dev/sd2 entry in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Thanks goys. I found a solution that worked for me here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/783061/automount-in-16-04. After following the steps, I shut down and rebooted Ubuntu and I can now access /dev/sda2.