# Link to NTFS partition broken after reboot

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs, symbolic-link

I've created a link to a folder located on a NTFS partition, in the same HDD where Ubuntu is installed. After rebooting, the link says it's broken (the link shows a lock icon to the lower right and won't work). The NTFS partition is set to Auto-Mount, just like it is answered in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically).

What could the problem be?

Comment: Actually I really don't like GUI ways to set automount, look into the dupe link. It simply is not automounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. I had to add the following line in /etc/fstab:

UUID={The parition UUID} /media/sdb1 ntfs uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 0

and make the links again.