# SD card unmounts during suspend or hibernate

Tags: 15.10, suspend, sd-card

I have a laptop with only 32GB SSD space (Lenovo 100S). That's not very much, so when I installed Ubuntu 15.10, I set a 64GB SD card as the /home partition.

My problem is, every time I wake the laptop from suspend or hibernate, the SD card is unmounted and I have to reinsert it to re-mount it. How can I configure Ubuntu so that the SD card is acting like a normal System "SSD"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a program to mount all of my drives automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a graphic tool to do this, depending your environment.
But you can always *configure Ubuntu so that the SD card is acting like a normal System "SSD"* by editing the **fstab** file, in /etc/fstab. Maybe have a look to the doc about it if you are interested by this questions.
Have a look to yours with a text editor, and make a backup file before editing anything.
So then:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

You just have to specify uuid, the mount point desired, the file system used and leav the other option as defaults, 0, and 2.
Example for my home device:

```
# /home was on /dev/sde8 during installation
UUID=ab5346f-c35e-454e-7827-esd6g4ds5fab /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

But I don't know is there is a specific problem with suspend (it's possible).