# How to import music into a music player from another partition?

Tags: 17.10, rhythmbox, music-player

I've been having some problems on importing music to a music player. I have to import them manually every time I restart my computer. When I add music from Ubuntu's default music folder (/home/music), I don't have that problem. But when I try to add it from another partition (/dev/sda3), it keeps forgetting folder location. I have tried Rhythmbox and Lollypop so far; same issue in both of them.

Comment: Is sda3 mounted before you open Rhythmbox?

Comment: Hi, @MichaelBay. Unfortunately, I'm new to Ubuntu and don't understand the concept of mounting/unmounting (yet). I'm dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 17.10 and used to have my music folder in D: drive in Windows.

Comment: Mounting in this context means making the partition available, readable. Your sda3 (probably D: in Windows), being a non-system NTFS partition is typically not mounted until you click on it for instance in Files (equivalent to Windows Explorer), hence may question. If not mounted when you open the players they will "forget" that location because it no longer exists.

Comment: When I open Files and click "+ Other Locations", it shows me other partitions I have. When I right-click, for instance, /dev/sda3/,  it gives me choice to unmount. Does that mean they're mounted ?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you open it and can see your folder/files it is mounted.

Comment: So,  if they are mounted, what's causing the problem? Any ideas to fix?

Comment: Well, they are *now* but probaly not when you noticed the problem. Try adding the additional folder(s) (sources) now, confirm it's working as intended, then reboot and *before* opening the players, browse to the same location as you did now. Then open the players. Does the problem still occur?

Comment: You were right. I restarted Ubuntu, and went to Files -> Other Locations and they were unmounted (I right-clicked and it gave me option to mount). I opened Lollypop and it recognized the files! So, this partially solves my problem. Now, the question is : How do I make them mount automatically every time I start Ubuntu?

Comment: Many options... Perhaps the easiest one (because GUI) is with Disks. Follow this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/271527/692175 but I suggest also enabling "Show in user interface" and in "Identify as" select the option label in order to have a more "user friendly" name. Reboot. You may need to add the sources again because now it will have a different mount point and the programs may not recognize it as the same location. But once done is "set and forget". Should I make a full fledged answer with all the info in comments?

Comment: Thank you very much! This definitely solves my problems. You can turn this to an answer, if you want. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Done, you can click accept anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Players such as Rhythmbox often "forget" additional media sources when they are no longer detected. Your additional media sources are in `sda3` ("D:" in Windows. This partition is not automatically mounted.

In order to work around this behavior it is recommended to mount the partition on boot.

There are many ways to achieve that and - typically - advanced users would edit the `fstab`. But you can also do it entirely in a GUI by using the included Disks tool:

- Follow the instructions in this answer [Is there a program to mount all of my drives automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/a/271527/692175) but I suggest also enabling "Show in user interface" and in "Identify as" select the option Label in order to have a more "user friendly" name. Reboot. You may need to add the sources again because now it will have a different mount point and the programs may not recognize it as the same location. But once done is "set and forget".