# Mounting Windows drive on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I am unable to view or access my Windows drives on Ubuntu.

On running the sudo fdisk -lu command, this is what i get..

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2C0F5684-BD40-495A-9329-4AFEDB0FCC8F

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2      923648    1128447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1128448    1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1161216  408365677 407204462 194.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   408367104  409599999   1232896   602M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6   409602048 1181558783 771956736 368.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1181560832 1706778623 525217792 250.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  1706778624 1712779263   6000640   2.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda9  1712779264 1772779519  60000256  28.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda10 1772779520 1953523711 180744192  86.2G Linux filesystem
```

On running the blkid command, I get

```
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="cf85a6a9-6687-4a11-9455-d8f77694af57"
/dev/sda4: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="7546164d-6e43-4c87-af83-1c2ddb92e202"
/dev/sda6: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="4e34c2f9-519e-46bd-82dd-fdb17b9a3e94"
/dev/sda7: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f0c555f2-26ee-4fff-ab6b-0c10ac3721bb"
```

It is files on `/dev/sda6` and `/dev/sda7` (Microsoft basic data) that I want to mount.

Comment: Are you trying to access your Windows system partition (C: drive) or a shared partition?

Comment: I am trying to access the D and E drives in Windows. That is, the files in /dev/sda6 and /dev/sda7

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put images of the text in terminal. Format pasted text using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: How about `sudo mkdir /mnt/windows_e` then `sudo mount /dev/sda6/ /mnt/windows_e` ?

Comment: Welcome! You can use the Disks utility to mount partitions. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity not of much help. i have ubuntu 18.04 where the options are not exactly the same

Comment: @Biggybi this is what i get..  {mount: /mnt/windows_e: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda6, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.}

Comment: Use `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda6 /mnt/windows_e`. You need to specify the filesystem type for non-ext4 filesystems.

Comment: @Jos could you elaborate?

Comment: I agree with @Biggybi's answer, only I would add `-t ntfs` to indicate an NTFS filesystem. This will avoid the "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error.

Comment: @Jos oh yeah, I forgot about that!

Comment: @Biggybi and Jos, I tried that and it didn't work. It is showing NTFS signature missing. I guess this is because it is a 'Microsoft basic data' partition.Can u tell me how to mount these types of partitions

Comment: @SagnikGupta sorry, I'm afraid I can't do more. Maybe, check the partition type and try with it if it's not NTFS.