# Remember Ubuntu password but ask for sudo confirmation

Tags: password, prompt

When I'm done with making Ubuntu remember my password and do not ask for it before risky actions...

Is there a way to get safe pop up confirmation window (without password input, just `OK` or `cancel`)?

So I will know when a pesky program runs a risky action that I don't want to proceed?

Or it is not developed since the program could just simulate a click on `OK` anyway?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this. If you enable sudo without a password ([How to run sudo command with no password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password)), then any process you run can execute sudo and run code as root without any confirmation.

Answer (score -1):

Let's write a small program for that:

Create `/usr/local/bin/sudo`:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p "You sure you want to run sudo? " ans
case "$ans" in
y|Y|[yY][eE][sS]) ;;
*) exit ;;
esac
exec /bin/sudo "$@"
```

You could also create it in a temporary directory, add that directory to path before running that "pesky program". It's not 100% fullproff, but should handle most common cases.

Comment: Writing a script to replace the base `sudo` system, while it works, is not recommended because `sudo` is called from a LOT of other scripts and such without the full path - this will likely interfere with any other systems, programs, scripts, etc. calling `sudo`.