# Would like to use different passwords for initial login and sudo for encrypted home folder

Tags: login, password, sudo, ecryptfs

I just encrypted my home directory using `ecryptfs` and the instructions from [How to Encrypt Ubuntu Home Folder After Installation](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Encrypt-Ubuntu-Home-Folder-After-Installation-290037.shtml).

In order to really benefit from the encryption, however, I needed to change to a stronger and longer password for login. Typing in a long password once at login doesn't bother me, but it does get annoying to have to type in such a long password every time I use `sudo`.

How can I set my account to use two passwords: a strong long password for login and a weaker shorter password for `sudo` (with an `ecryptfs` encrypted home folder)?

Comment: really nice question, I also want that! could you do that in the end?

Comment: @brauliobo Sorry, didn't figure it out yet. If I do, I will be sure to post back here though.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely remove the need to enter a password for sudo: [How to run sudo command with no password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password)

I don't see any other way though, it's either entering the same sudo password or removing it.
I have a long password (about 20 characters) and it doesn't bother me. Also, entering a few sudo commands in succession only requires you to type the password once...
It doesn't bother me because my password is easy to type fast. Lots of people make a password too complicated, either to remember or to type. Personally I think this is wrong. If you have a long password that is easy to type, people can't follow your keystrokes when they're watching. If you do have a complicated password that takes time to type. There is lots to be said about passwords and they're never-ending discussions. I'm personally convinced that it's better to use a long password (even using normal dictionary words, including spaces and other punctuation) than a complicated short password. The longer the password, the longer (exponentially) it takes to crack. Using common sentences (e.g. `I had bacon and eggs for breakfast.`), makes it easy to remember, very strong but also easy and fast to type. You will find people who strongly object because they're all dictionary words, but I can assure you they're more difficult to crack than e.g. `P@5s\/\/0Rd`, which is considered by most as a very strong password.