# Why do I need sudo to run apt-mirror?

Tags: sudo, apt-mirror

Why do I need `sudo` to run `apt-mirror`? Is there a way to run `apt-mirror` without `sudo`?

Comment: Because it is an instruction for administrators and not for a user. We believe in a strict separation of tasks and if it is for admin it requires sudo. Why does it bother you to type 5 extra characters and a password?  Regarding your question: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password on how to do this.

Comment: What is that `apt-mirror` does that requires admin rights? I just want to download a copy of the repository to my local PC. Why is that an administrator's task? I understand that *installing* something from that repository requires `sudo`, but just making a copy of the files shouldn't require admin.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-mirror` uses port 21 [courtesy of ProFTPd] (all ports below 1024 require root), and stores information in `/etc`, `/var`, or `/opt`. As none of these locations are user-writable, `sudo` is required.

You may be able to get away by making `apt-mirror` store to a place you have write-access to, such as `/home/$USER/.local-repo`. `sudo` will still be needed to install programs from your mirror, though.

ProFTPd runs as a daemon, so you won't need to worry about that.

Comment: How did proftpd come in to the picture?

Comment: @muru `apt-mirror` can use ProFTPd to give packages to localhost.

Comment: It can also use apache, nginx, etc. So?