# how to run as administrator ubuntu 14.04 and not as guest?

Tags: wireless, root, authentication, administrator

today I installed ubuntu 14.04 and also a new user to the new operating sysytem.
there are several problems I am facing with it 
they are:
1.I cant log in as administrator but as guest,can you help me fix that.
2.I cant connent to **wifi** as it askes the **authentication**.but with ethernet its not so.
 plzzzz help me !!!

Comment: It's not possible to do a graphical login as root for a good reason. You chould breake your whole system if you do so. Applications you start would have complete root permissions as well and could break anything. But if you need to run a command as root, you can do it with `sudo command`. Sudo needs a password. In Ubuntu it is normally the password of the user you created in the installation

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find your answers by googling!

In order to run a command with root privilege, you can use sudo or su commands. (your authentication password was set when you were installing Ubuntu). if you are using a live cd,for authentication just press Enter.

There are many many Ubuntu tutorials on the web, just take a look at some of them. Your problems will solved quickly!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to login as root (administrator) from the login screen on Ubuntu.

When you do something that does require administrator rights, you type in your password for your user, if it's the first user created on the machine.

To do this in terminal when executing commands as administrator just use "sudo" in front of the regular commands and type in your password.

You only have this password if your user is the first user created on the system.

Answer (score 0):

the 1st q: [How to run sudo command with no password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password/443071#443071)
to become root: `sudo su`

WiFi asks authentication because the owner of WiFi access point set it up this way. He did not want to allow free access to his internet. So contact him and talk.