# Bleachbit cron problems

Tags: cron, bleachbit

I've been trying to get gnome-schedule to automate bleachbit but the crons never work.
So after trying a lot different things I decided to just try setting crons the normal way.
I opened terminal and used *crontab -e* and entered the following.

```
* * * * * echo hello world > /home/ubdt2/file.txt
```

This worked.

So then I went with:

```
* * * * * echo The monthly disk cleanup requires root level permission, please enter your root password; sudo bleachbit --preset --clean; >/dev/null 2>&1
```

It doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, *where* do you suppose to put the sudo password? To work from cron programs should never ask user input. Use root crontab or see http://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password